# In jQuery, cannot use a hover function into an each function?

Tags: jquery

This is probably an easy question, but since I'm new to jQuery, I need someone to look at this code for me. So basically I want to change the css of the hover state of multiple anchor tags, I tried the following code but it didn't work. What's wrong with that?

```
(".p-container a").each(function () {
    $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 0.2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    $(this).hover(function() {
           $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    },function() {
           $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 0.2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    });
    i++;
});
```

The code works without having the hover function, but I want to change the css of the hover state at the same time. Is anybody know how to do that?

Thanks
KJ

Comment: I also tried to change the "$(this)" under the hover function to the specific selector, didn't work either.

Comment: Of course you can use `hover` but you have a scope problem with `i` (google for `javascript closure loop` or similar). What exactly is `i` for? If it just counts the iterations, then use the index passed to the `each` callback, this will solve your problem.

Comment: Where does this `i` come from? It's not defined in your example.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I declare both the i and colorArray outside of the loop, and as just what I said, the code works without the hover function so neither colorArray nor i is the problem

Answer (score 0):

What is you `i`? Is it the index of the `.each()`[<sup>**DOC**</sup>](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function?

```
(".p-container a").each(function (i, value) {
    $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 0.2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    $(this).hover(function() {
           $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    },function() {
           $(this).css({'text-shadow':'0 0 0.2px '+ colorArray[i]});
    });
    i++;
});
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I declare both the i and colorArray outside of the loop, and as just what I said, the code works without the hover function so neither colorArray nor i is the problem

Answer (score 0):

If `i` is a problem so do `colorArray`. `i` could be a global variable.
I think the problem is missing `$`

```
$(".p-container a").each(function () {
```